# Unviewable videos on Ubuntu 18.04 and Chromium

Tags: chromium, video-streaming

After a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 I have serious problems with Chromium web browser an video streaming. Every few seconds of video playback whole system freezes for a couple of seconds, eating CPU cycles and repeating again and again.

- Processor: Intel i7-6500U with integrated HD Graphics 520.
- Same problem with Xorg and Wayland, but with Wayland is significantly worse.
- It happens with and without full screen viewing.
- I am using standard gnome shell, but same problem with Ubuntu default one.
- It is a system freeze not an Internet connection issue.
- Firefox freezes too. Not as bad as Chromium, but it definitively does.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you run video full screen ? Which graphic card do you have ? do you run xorg or wayland ? gnome shell ? Check with firefox to be sure. Are you sure it is the system freezing and not the internet connection ?

Comment: @solsTiCe Question edited with requested info.

Comment: Same problem here with the following :
Intel I3 1.70GHz x 4 ; Integrated Intel HD graphics ; chromium 69.0.3497.81 ; Ubuntu 18.04 clean install.
No problem using firefox.
In my case, only the video freezes, sound carries on normally.